# Return data from controller to ajax laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

I want to show notifications when new row inserted.I've achieved it through the below code,
**Ajax**

```
<script>

    var old_count = 0;
    var i=0;
    setInterval(function(){    
    $.ajax({

    url : "shownotify",
    success : function(data){
    if (data > old_count) 
    { 
        if (i == 0)
        {old_count = data;} 
        else{
        $('#notify').html("New user");
        old_count = data;
        }
    } i=1;
 }
});
},1000);                                
        </script>
```

Now I want to show the count of new users which I returned from controller,

```
public function shownotify()
{
     $action=DB::table('users')->where('admin_action_at', 'null')->count();
     $data=Move::count();

    return compact('action', 'data');

}
```

How do I get it in ajax function?Can anybody help?

Comment: Where do you want to show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the array `$data` but you are passing a string.

```
public function shownotify()
{
     $action=DB::table('users')->where('admin_action_at', 'null')->count();
     $data=Move::count();

    $return_array = compact('action', 'data');
    return json_encode($return_array);

}
```

And make a little change in your ajax success callback function like:

```
success : function(data){
if (data.data > old_count) 
{ 
    if (i == 0)
    {old_count = data.data;} 
    else{
    $('#notify').html(data.data + "New user");
    old_count = data.data;
    }
} i=1;
```

Comment: I wnt to display the count of user newly added like `$('#notify').html(+count+"New user");`

Comment: @saranya, check my updated answer. I have again changed `'$data'` to `'data'` and I have also suggested some change in ajax code too.

Comment: My pleasure. Happy to help.